# Excel VBA: Type mismatch in incremental variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA and i have been fighting with this tiny piece of code for over a day now so i turn to you, my knowledge superiors.

I have the following situation:

The end goal is to get 4 variables: ADR1, ADR2, ADR3 and ADR4. These variables should be created by an IF function that compares 4 sets of cells with one target cell (found in the IF and ELSIF parts).

When finding a match between these cells, I want to assign a certain cell value to the variable ADR1. Once the value is added to variable ADR1, the loop will start again to assign a value to ADR2 and so on until ADR4.

In order to create the four variables ADR1-4, i used a 'for I = 1 to 4' statement.

When i execute this code i get a 'type mismatch error' on line 'ADR(I) = Cells(1, "B").Value' so the first ELSIF part.

Could anyone of you explain to me why i am getting this mismatch and how it should be solved?

```
Sub variable_incrementation()

    'resetting variables
ADR1 = 0
ADR2 = 0
ADR3 = 0
ADR4 = 0
Dim N As Integer
N = 4

Dim ADR(1 To 4) As Long
Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To 4

Do

'N is supposed to increase by steps of four due to the target cells that contain the matching information

N = N + 4
    If Activesheet.Cells.(2, "A") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
       Activesheet.Cells.(3, "A") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Then
     ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "A").Value

    ElseIf Activesheet.Cells.(2, "B") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(3, "B") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(4, "B") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Then
         ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "B").Value

    ElseIf Activesheet.Cells.(2, "C") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(3, "C") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(4, "C") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(5, "C") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Then
         ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "C").Value

    ElseIf Activesheet.Cells.(2, "D") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(3, "D") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Or _
           Activesheet.Cells.(4, "D") = Activesheet.Cells.(N, "D") Then
         ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "D").Value
    Else
    End If

    Loop Until (IsEmpty(ADR) = False) Or (N <= 43)
Next I


For J = 1 To 4
MsgBox (ADRJ)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure the value on the ActiveSheet, since this is what you are searching without stating the parent of the range object in that cell is a number and not text or an error.

Comment: Cells() method requires two integer values (rowindex and columnindex), why are you providing strings?

Comment: @avb the column can be a string, VBA will parse it to the column number.

Comment: @ScottCraner, really works, Excel will never stop suprising me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the array as `Long`

```
Dim ADR(1 To 4) As Long
```

And hence when you try to store a value which is not a number you will get the `Type Mismatch` error. You may want to declare it as a `Variant` or have additional checks to see if it is a number or not

Comment: Alright, that seems to have worked indeed, i do not get the mismatch error anymore. The only issue that i run into now is that it does not produce 4 variables. When i add a msgbox(ADR1 & ADR2 & ADR3 & ADR4) at the end of the code then i get an empty msgbox. I retraced the problem and i found out that if i msgbox (ADR(I)) that i do get the desired result. It seems that the macro is assigning the result to a variable that is called ADR(I) and not to ADR1 - 4.

Comment: That is maybe because the conditions are not being met :)

Comment: I eddited my previous comment so just to repeat:  I retraced the problem and i found out that if i msgbox (ADR(I)) that i do get the desired result. It seems that the macro is assigning the result to a variable that is called ADR(I) and not to ADR1 - 4.

Comment: I just checked your code. And I see lot of issues. ADR(I) is being written but it is also getting overwritten. Try this for me. Change `ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "A").Value` to `If Len(Trim(ADR(I))) = 0  then ADR(I) = Activesheet.Cells.(1, "A").Value` Similarly do it for others. and now check the value

Comment: I see what you mean, i tried your sollution but the msgboxes still come up empty.